# Code to check how many posts a tag has?

Tags: tags, template-tags

I would like to noindex any of my /tag/ pages that have less than three posts attributed to them. Any idea how I would go about doing that?

I know `is_tag()` of course, but am not aware if there is any way to delve further to check how many posts a tag has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`found_posts` property](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#properties) of the `WP_Query` class, to get the total number of posts in the queried tag (`post_tag` taxonomy), provided that the [`no_found_rows` argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Query/parse_query/) is **not** `true`:

```php
global $wp_query;
$total_posts = $wp_query->found_posts;
```

Working example using the [`wp_robots` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_robots/) to add `noindex` (and also `follow`) to the `robots` meta tag on single tag archive pages:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_robots', 'wpse_408229_add_noindex' );
function wpse_408229_add_noindex( $robots ) {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( is_tag() && $wp_query->found_posts < 3 ) {
        $robots['noindex'] = true;
        $robots['follow']  = true;
    }

    return $robots;
}
```

You could also use the `post_count` property if you're sure that the `posts_per_page` setting was `3` or more. I.e. You'd instead use `$wp_query->post_count < 3`.

And if you're doing this for a hierarchical taxonomy like the core `category` taxonomy and you just wanted to get the total number of posts that were *directly* attached to the current category (i.e. not its children), then you could use the `count` property of the category/term [object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/), e.g. `get_queried_object()->count < 3`.